# Perf Tool monitoring by PID

Tags: linux, process, profiling, perf

I'm using [linux perf tool](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) to monitor the performance of some processes. The documentation tells that you can flag it to collect profiles on per-thread, per-process and per-cpu basis.

I get that the processor would have performance registers collecting event-counts for a given physical-core and it's resources (e.g. L1-caches).

How does `perf` or any such performance monitoring tool, measure counters per-process or per-thread basis? For example, let's say I'm monitoring L1-cache-misses, now since the cache is shared for all processes running on that CPU, how does `perf` determine how many misses came from a given process or a given thread?

Comment: "How does perf or any such performance monitoring tool, measure counters per-process or per-thread basis? " this Q could be overly broad.

Comment: dtrace type monitoring was built into the Linux kernel - http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2016-10-27/dtrace-for-linux-2016.html. Methods used to collect perf data are covered here - http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html.